# Is there a way to avoid this memory error?

Tags: python, memory, pypy

I'm currently working through the problems on Project Euler, and so far I've come up with this code for a problem.

```
from itertools import combinations
import time

def findanums(n):
    l = []
    for i in range(1, n + 1):
        s = []
        for j in range(1, i):
            if i % j == 0:
                s.append(j)
        if sum(s) > i:
            l.append(i)
    return l

start = time.time() #start time

limit = 28123

anums = findanums(limit + 1) #abundant numbers (1..limit)
print "done finding abundants", time.time() - start

pairs = combinations(anums, 2)
print "done finding combinations", time.time() - start

sums = map(lambda x: x[0]+x[1], pairs)
print "done finding all possible sums", time.time() - start

print "start main loop"
answer = 0
for i in range(1,limit+1):
    if i not in sums:
        answer += i
print "ANSWER:",answer
```

When I run this I run into a `MemoryError`.

The traceback:

```
File "test.py", line 20, in <module>
    sums = map(lambda x: x[0]+x[1], pairs)
```

I've tried to prevent it by disabling garbage collection from what I've been able to get from Google but to no avail. Am I approaching this the wrong way? In my head this feels like the most natural way to do it and I'm at a loss at this point.

SIDE NOTE: I'm using PyPy 2.0 Beta2(Python 2.7.4) because it is so much faster than any other python implementation I've used, and Scipy/Numpy are over my head as I'm still just beginning to program and I don't have an engineering or strong math background.

Comment: How much memory you got ? is the system 64-bit ?

Comment: 64-bit, 8 GB of memory, although PyPy is 32-bit if that makes a difference as well.

Comment: You appear to have a bug somewhere. If you `print len(anums)` after `findanums` runs, it gives `28123`, meaning _every_ number from one to 28123 is an abundant number. I don't think that's correct.

Comment: Python 64 bit as well ?

Comment: Kevin, the error was that `for j in range(1, i + 1)` had `i + 1`, I fixed this.

Comment: @JesseNeff what you fixed it to ? I edited my answer with more info

Comment: Changed to `for j in range(1, i)` @Ofiris

Comment: @JesseNeff, use `xrange` as well, it cuts 10 seconds on my machine.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As Kevin mention in the comments, your algorithm might be wrong, but anyway your code is not optimized.

When using very big lists, it is common to use `generators`, there is a famous, great Stackoverflow answer explaining the concepts of `yield` and `generator` - [What does the "yield" keyword do in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/231767/the-python-yield-keyword-explained)

The problem is that your `pairs = combinations(anums, 2)` doesn't generate a `generator`, but generates a large object which is much more memory consuming.

I changed your code to have this function, since you iterating over the collection only once, you can lazy evaluate the values:

```
def generator_sol(anums1, s):
      for comb in itertools.combinations(anums1, s):
        yield comb
```

Now instead of `pairs = combinations(anums, 2)` which generates a large object.
Use:

```
pairs = generator_sol(anums, 2)
```

Then, instead of using the `lambda` I would use another `generator`:

```
sums_sol = (x[0]+x[1] for x in pairs)
```

Another tip, you better look at [xrange](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#xrange) which is more suitable, it doens't generate a list but an `xrange object` which is more efficient in many cases (such as here).

Comment: Now it's just spitting out a wrong answer. You have given me a lot to read and learn so for that I thank you. The generator did indeed solve my memory issue!

Comment: Good luck with the Project Euler.

Comment: range does not generate a list in pypy either

Answer (score 2):

Let me suggest you to use [generators](http://wiki.python.org/moin/Generators). Try changing this:

```
sums = map(lambda x: x[0]+x[1], pairs)
```

to

```
sums = (a+b for (a,b) in pairs)
```

Ofiris solution is also ok but implies that `itertools.combinations` return a list when it's wrong. If you are going to keep solving project euler problems have a look at the [itertools documentation](http://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html).

Comment: What do you mean by `combinations` returns a list when it's wrong?

Comment: I said combination returns a `list` and its not correct, fixed it anyhow.

Comment: combinations is a generator thus you don't need to worry about `pairs = combinations(anums, 2)`, it's not memory hungry. And is very good practice :)

Comment: @Alex, I figured as much, it was the mapping of the sums of the tuples that gave me a memory error.

Answer (score 1):

The issue is that anums is big - about 28000 elements long. so pairs must be 28000*28000*8 bytes = 6GB. If you used numpy you could cast anums as a numpy.int16 array, in which case the result pairs would be 1.5GB - more manageable:

```
import numpy as np
#cast
anums = np.array([anums],dtype=np.int16)
#compute the sum of all the pairs via outer product
pairs = (anums + anums.T).ravel()
```

Comment: As I said in my post I'm still quite green and numpy's magic is still out of my grasp at the moment as I am still learning the normal Python libraries. But I appreciate this answer nonetheless as it gives me a taste of what I'd be able to do once I learn enough to use numpy/scipy!